# No dates in search results for community wiki post

Tags: bug, search, community-wiki, dates

Searching for [regular](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A0) (non-wiki) posts results with a list of posts with visible dates (asked, answered...):

> [image]

If you do search for [wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1) posts there're no dates at all:

> [image]

Could we please add dates for wiki posts displayed in search results list as well as for regular posts?